# conference model - create schedule method (Sequelize)

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

```
var _ = require('lodash');
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
var ResourceNotFound = require('./errors').ResourceNotFound;
var ResourceAccessDenied = require('./errors').ResourceAccessDenied;
var ResourceExpired = require('./errors').ResourceExpired;

var ConferenceState = {
    NEW: 'new',
    ...
};

module.exports.define = function define(options) {

    var sequelize = options.sequelize;

    return sequelize.define('conference', {

        id: {
            type: Sequelize.UUID,
            defaultValue: Sequelize.UUIDV4,
            primaryKey: true
        },

        startDate: {
            type: Sequelize.DATE,
        },

        endDate: {
            type: Sequelize.DATE,
        },

        state: {
            type: Sequelize.ENUM(
                ConferenceState.NEW,
                ...
            ),
            defaultValue: ConferenceState.NEW,
            required: true,
            allowNull: false
        }
    }, {
      classMethods: {

           getOrCreateConference: function createConference(data) {

               return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

                   var Conference = sequelize.models.conference;
                   Conference.findOne({
                       where: data
                   }).then(function(conference){
                       if(_.isObject(conference)) {
                           resolve(conference);
                       } else {
                           return Conference.create(data);
                       }
                   }).then(function(conference){
                       resolve(conference);
                   }).catch(function(err){
                       reject(err);
                   });
               });
           },

          scheduleConference: function scheduleConference(start, end) {
              // TODO
          },
      }
  });
};
```

My question is now a theoretical one on how to approach the following task:

- Conference must be schedulable

So the conference has a fix start and end date. It has to have those fields with values and it is also not possible to join when it is not started yet or has ended. Otherwise it will throw an error.

So I need a mehtode that says, that I want to schedule a conference and pass start/end values.

Can this be done within one single method or should it be split up? What methods would I need and what would they basically do in their procedure?

Comment: What exactly do you want your method to do? Simply set `startDate` and `endDate` of the conference or some other actions also?

Comment: @piotrbienias Yes, that is the minimal requirement. Other method later would be to join the conference and check if it is still valid (start, end) and other validations.

Comment: Why I downvoted this question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down#:~:text=When%20should%20I%20vote%20down,also%20need%20to%20be%20closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your comment, your `scheduleConference` method must simply update specified instance (conference). You did put it in `classMethods`, however I suggest you put it in `instanceMethods` and it's simple implementation may be as follows:

```
classMethods: {
},
instanceMethods: {
    scheduleConference: function(start, end){
        return this.update({ startDate: start, endDate: end }).then((conference) => {
             // here you get updated instance of conference
             return reference;
        });
    }
}
```

Above method can be used in such way

```
// assuming that conference is a sequelize model instance
conference.scheduleConference(start, end).then((self) => {
    // updated conference as self
});
```

---

**EDIT**

I see that you have implemented `getOrCreateConference` method, however sequelize offers this kind of method by itself and it is called [**`findOrCreate`**](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/model/#findorcreateoptions-promiseinstance-created). You can use it on sequelize model like `models.Model.findOrCreate()`